# How to using UPDATE and SELECT in one Transaction SQL

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table: [dbo].[Product]
with data :

```
ID          Name
01          Keyboard
02          Monitor
03          Mouse
04          RAM
05          HDD
```

And then I have one transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN
      UPDATE Product SET Name = 'XXX' WHERE ID = 01
      SELECT Name as Name_in_Trans FROM Product WHERE ID = 01
COMMIT TRAN 
     SELECT Name as Name_out_Trans FROM Product WHERE ID = 01
```

Result:

```
Name_in_Trans
XXX

Name_out_Trans
XXX
```

I don't know this result correct or incorrect!.

Answer (score 2):

The first select is within the same transaction as the update, so it will see any non-committed data in that transaction - in your case, the `XXX` value. The second select is after the transaction is committed, at which point any query should see the updated data. Long story short - both queries should see the `XXX`, this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Hi, Mureinik! I would ask, and then update command, I want to check XXX value exists in the Product table yet, but result Name_in_trans = XXX, I want to result Name_in_trans = 'Keyboard' (original), what should I do ?

Comment: @philong it's very hard to have a conversation like this in the comments. If you have a new question, please post it as a question, so it can more easily be answered.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct.

```
BEGIN TRAN
      UPDATE Product SET Name = 'XXX' WHERE ID = 01
      SELECT Name as Name_in_Trans FROM Product WHERE ID = 01
COMMIT TRAN 
     SELECT Name as Name_out_Trans FROM Product WHERE ID = 01
```

`BEGIN TRAN` will start your transaction and `COMMIT TRAN` will commit the transaction to the database.

`UPDATE` is setting the `Name` field of your `Product` table to 'XXX', only on the field where the `ID` field is 01. The transaction hasn't been committed, but since it's in the middle of it, a `SELECT` will show that change until the transaction is rolled back.

After committing the transaction, that change has been committed to the database, so selecting the `Name` field from your `Product` table will still show 'XXX' since it's now effective in the database.

Comment: If I want Name_in_Trans is empty, what should I do ?

Comment: @philong, Why would you want it to be empty? You're using it as an alias for a field so it's going to come back with whatever that field has in it. If you want it to be empty you'd have to use `SELECT '' as Name_in_Trans`, though I don't think that makes very much sense.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake, I would ask, and then update command, I want to check XXX value exists in the Product table yet, but result Name_in_trans = XXX, I want to result Name_in_trans = 'Keyboard' (original), what should I do ?

Comment: You would either have to not update the `Name` field in the first place or perform another update statement setting it back to 'Keyboard'. `UPDATE Product SET Name = 'XXX' WHERE ID = 01`. You could use another transaction for that. Though I feel you're aware of this and I'm misunderstanding somewhere.